# Find even numbers between N number of cases in C

Tags: c, int, case, intervals

I want to make a code were you find all the even numbers between N number of cases(y). The next y lines will contain a n number (1<=n1<=100). For each line I want to find the even numbers between these. So for example:

```
input:
2 (number of cases; 1<=y<=10)
1
7
Output:
No even numbers
2 4 6
```

If there is no even numbers between them then print "No even numbers" for example:

So what I've made up until now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n1, n2, i, j, p, y;
    printf("number of intervals: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for(j=1; j<=y; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n1);
        for(i=1;i<=n1; i++)
        {
            p=i%2;
            if(p==0)
                printf(" %d", i);     
        }
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

The thing is that I dont know how to implement the number of intervals to the code, it only works with two intervals.

Comment: If you could explain in more detail how `2 1 7` leads to `2 4 6`, that would greatly help us to help you :-) It *looks* like you're generating the even numbers between `1` and `7` but surely that's only *one* case rather than two.

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside your outer `for` loop. That will cause the program to terminate after the first iteration. Move the `return` to be outside the loops.

Comment: @paxdiablo My understanding of the question is that the first value represents the number of subsequent inputs. Then for each subsequent input, n, the OP wants to print even numbers in the range [1-n]. So in the example given there will be 2 subsequent numbers. First number `1` has no even numbers in the interval. Second number `7` has the even numbers `2, 4, 6` in the corresponding interval.

Comment: @kaylum Yes, you are right, that is basically what I want to find.

Comment: @Redspark77 Like I said, move the `return` and your program will work. Oh, and you are also missing the handling of the "No even numbers" case.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks a lot! One more question, where should I add the "No even numbers" case? Thanks again.

Comment: @Redspark77 Keep a counter that is initialised to 0 before the inner `for` loop starts. Increment every time you find an even number. Check the counter after the inner `for` loop completes. If counter is `0` then print "No even numbers". Or just check for the numbers `0` and `1`. Those are the only numbers that fall into that case :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good idea to make a function if you want to do similar thing with different values.You can make a function and call that function as many time as you need.For example

```
void printInterval(int n1, int n2){  //function will print all even 
    for(i=n1;i<=n2; i++)//number between n1 and n2 (both inclusive)
    {
        p=i%2;
        if(p==0)
        printf(" %d", i);   

    }
}
```

Comment: Good advice. But not sure how that answers the actual question.

Comment: You input the interval starting and ending point in main and call the printInterval(int,int) function to print all the even number in that interval.

Comment: Right. But that's not what the OP is asking. The OP is asking why the code shown doesn't work. What you have offered is a restructuring of the code.

Comment: Yeah that is restructuring of code but I think it's always better to stick to good programming practice.

Comment: this line: `for(i=n1;i<=n2; i++)` does not implement the 'between n1 and n2 as it will include n1 and n2 in the calculation.   suggest: `for(i=n1+1; i<n2; i++)`  or perhaps the comment should be: `in the range n1...n2 inclusive`